# cannot get css file to link to html

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my first high-level project for Codecademy, and I can't seem to link the CSS file to the HTML file. Here is my file structure:

`C:\Projects\Dasmoto\Resources\css\index.css`

My HTML file is here:

`C:\Projects\Dasmoto\index.html`

This is the code I have right now, which seems to be incorrect when I view it in the browser, because none of my CSS shows up:

`<link href="/Dasmoto/Resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You forgot `C:\Projects`! Use a relative URL.

Comment: Oh shoot! Let me try that!

Comment: That didn't work for me :/

Comment: `<link href="/Resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 1):

Don't type the word /Dasmoto again, since you are already in the same folder/directory. 
Also you seem to have written the file name wrong. I mean the path shows index.css and you have linked style.css. 
The two file names should be written correctly without any spelling errors.

```
<link href="/Resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Still no CSS is showing up. I viewed the Codecademy solution, and it doesn't look like theirs is showing up, either. Maybe it's a Firefox problem?

Comment: Okay. I hope you get your problem solved soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a mistake here

```
<link href="/Dasmoto/Resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">
```

Your address is wrong so type this

```
<link href="C:/Projects/Domasto/Resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Bro `<link href="/Dasmoto/Resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
problame is here "Style.css" u must rename to ur real file name like this `<link href="/Resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">`

your problame in directory and name of the file, you write there style.css but your file name is index.css, you got that?

Comment: I fixed it and it still didn't work, haha. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0):

tried this and it worked:

`<link href="./resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" ref="stylesheet">`

Comment: How come ..isn't the resources folder in the same root like you depicted in your question? Weird.